# Web automation with Selenium Python CSV automation script

Tags: python, forms, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am currently trying to do a CSV to form submit script. My code currently runs however I need a more efficient memory management way in place, instead of new windows I want one instance of Chrome to submit the form and once it does then it needs to just keep refilling the form with content from the CSV. My code:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Imports
import csv
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setup

# name = 0
# age = 1
# score = 2

with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Web Automation

    for line in csv_reader:

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
        driver.get('site')

        time.sleep(3)
        title_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="TITLE"]')
        title_field.send_keys(line[0])

        fname_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FIRSTNAME"]')
        fname_field.send_keys(line[1])

        lname_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LASTNAME"]')
        lname_field.send_keys(line[2])
        
        phone_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[5]/form/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/input[2]')
        phone_field.send_keys(line[3])

        mail_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="EMAIL"]')
        mail_field.send_keys(line[4])

        submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s-form"]/div[9]/div/button')
        submit.click()

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Another issue I have Selenium and versions with Chrome, is there anyway to ensure if just uses a version that will work with Chrome ? The end game is this will be packaged as an exe as an alternative to APIs that do not work. Any assistance really appreciate on all the points

Answer (score 0):

It most likely won't work as an exe on its own.

Selenium is highly dependent on the chrome version and suitable chromedrivers.

With that said you can make it "portable" with a file selector where someone selects the current chromedriver. Said file selector needs to filter files only to chromedriver/gecko....exe possibly by name of the file selected to choose a matching browser.

You need to set a system variable through code pointing to the file selected and whatnot. This needs to be done before the program starts, have a button saying ready or similar that checks the system variable was created properly and opens the matching browser to then procceed with the program.

Comment: Hmmmm alright so a standalone program will be a real workaround ? This app needs to read and submit over 400 forms ,how can I do it so it doesnt open a new window ,just the one with the one tab running

Comment: That depends on how you code your program.  You can code a program that reads the CSV line by line and then goes back to the start page after submitting each time in order to submit with the next values. Again this would still need the Chromedriver file explorer and users to know how to find a version that is compatible with their version of chrome